# Проблемы с кодировкой (PHP)

Tags: php, кодировка

При чтении запроса, текст с кириллицей отображается не корректно.

```
 file_get_contents('php://input')
```

> С‚РµСЃС‚ - тест

Сам файл сохранен в utf-8 + header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8').

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: попробуйте через fopen

Comment: Есть кодировки: сам файл, его содержимое, трансфер (при чтении файла), трансфер (ХТМЛ). Есть у меня предчувствие, что Вы настроили кодировку символов файла, но не сам файл

Comment: Как настроить кодировку самого файла?

Comment: В редакторе выбрать "сохранить как". Хотя (по моему опыту) проще открыть док в нужной кодировке и пересохранить

Answer (score 1):

Проблема скорее всего кроется в том что у вас файл закодирован в UTF-8 With BOM - этот юникод используется в системе Windows. Я так подозреваю что ваш веб сервер стоит на системе Linux/freeBSD  и даже помоему в денвере такая проблема встречается и под виндой. Вам понадобиться редактор Notepad++. Откройте ваш файл в этом редакторе, откройте меню кодировки - ваша кодировка будет подсвечена, если это кодировка просто UTF-8 то я был прав, вам нужно выбрать пункт ниже - Преобразовать в UTF-8 без BOM, именно преобразовать! Сохраните файл, теперь кодировка соответствует никсовой и русские буквы будут отображаться корректно.

Comment: Стоит utf-8 без BOM, переношу файлы с винды через winscp на линукс.

Comment: Ну если в самом нотпаде с такой кодировкой символы отображаются верно можно пойти с другой стороны. В 32х битной версии нотпада есть встроенный фтп клиент, установите это расширение, подключитесь к серверу, и откройте ваш файл. Еще раз проверьте кодировку.

Comment: Да вроде все ок, но результат тот же.

Comment: Тогда если сервер ваш, вам остается покопаться в настройках апача там может быть указана кодировка по умолчанию не соответсвующая UTF-8, можете посмотреть [здесь](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-htaccess-charset.ru) У себя на freeBSD я использую очень хорошую вещь для управления сервером - [WebMin](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/webmin) можно производить практически все настройки сервера используя графический интерфейс